# Where are the Unity images located, can I access them?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I wanna theme Ubuntu Unity on Natty Narwhal but I don't know where they are or if I can even do this. Like the transparent background, icons, all of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some of the images Unity uses in `/usr/share/unity/themes`. You can try editing these. For other things like the top panel, windows and general icons (stuff you can theme under normal GNOME), check out a site like [GNOME-Look.org](http://gnome-look.org/) for a wide variety of pre-made themes, some of which were designed with Unity in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Which images?

Assuming you mean icons since that's the most common change related to images for theming, they're located in /usr/share/icons

Comment: Like the transparent background, icons, all of it.

Comment: @AvatarKava, I think he wants to theme things like the panel, launcher background, etc. Those things are located elsewhere.